# Matrix main diagonal change

Tags: matlab

I have matrix below: `a=`

```
1  2
1  2
```

I would like to transform it to: `b=`

```
1  1
2  2
```

I have tried to use output of `diag(a)`, but I don't know how to concatenate same output twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're swapping the anti-diagonal elements.  Another way instead of using a transpose is to just do indexing:

```
a([2 3]) = a([3 2]);
```

How the above code works is that you can access elements in a matrix using column-major linear indices.  This means that you traverse a matrix from top to bottom, left to right.  Therefore, we want to access the second row first column by index 2, then the first row second column by index 3.  All you have to do is swap the two values, where the left-side indices are the reverse of the right-side indices.

Answer (score 1):

you need just to transpose your matrix `b=transpose(a);`

Comment: For matrix transposition is still possible to use the symbol ``

Comment: I would personally do `b = a.';`  It's much easier to understand... not only because it's less typing, but because if you have an expression with multiple transpositions, typing `transpose` for each transpose operation is a pain in the @$$.